# Render the content of an object from firebase with map()

Tags: javascript, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database, array-map

Ok i have grid div where i show the content of a firebase branch and righ now it's like this:

the firebase snapshot:

```
database.ref('orders').on('value', snapshot => 
           {
               let orderList = [];
               snapshot.forEach(snap => {

                orderList.push(snap.val());

               });

               this.setState({ orderList: orderList });
           });
```

```
{this.state.orderList.map(orderData => {

    console.log(typeof orderData.order);
    
    var order = orderData.order;
    var adress = orderData.finalFormValues;
    return(
        <>
        <h3>Cliente: {orderData.displayName}</h3>    
        Horário do pedido: {orderData.horaLocal}<br />
        {Object.values(order).map(ordersData => {

            return(<>Sabores: {ordersData.name}<br /></>);

        })}

        {Object.entries(adress).map(adressData => {

        return(<>{adressData}<br /></>);

        })}
        </>
    );
})}
```

It's working but not as it would fit in the project:

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUHBW.png)

I can show the order value with map() but can't with adress. The following code doesen't render anything:

```
{Object.values(adress).map(adressData => {

    return(<>Rua: {adressData.rua}<br /></>);

})}
```

It doesn't render nothing.

A picture of my database:

[image: database]

Comment: `finalFormValues` seems like an object, not an array. Can you simply just `<>Rua: {adressData.rua}<br /></>` without the `map`?

Comment: Please edit your question to also show how you load the data from Firebase.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.